# Error:Failed to complete Gradle execution

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am new to android. I just started a new project in android studio. I have an error in my console. Error is:

```
Error:Failed to complete Gradle execution.  
Cause:
Process 'command '/opt/android-studio/jre/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

Does anybody have any idea what is causing this error?

here is my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.root.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: Do you have any library in your libs folder?

Comment: No i just have created this project. lib is empty.

Comment: I think you have some problem with your java. You are using windows?

Comment: No, it is kali linux.

Comment: yes @jonathanrz I found the Solution. you were right . Problem was in Jdk path. i set jdk path in project manually and everything is working perfect.

Comment: nice, I'm happy that you solved it :)

Comment: I will create an answer for documentation purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the error description it says Process 'command '/opt/android-studio/jre/bin/java'.

Your java path are define to your jre environment.

You need to set it to your jdk environment.